# Baker’s ratio for crackers

Tags: baking, bread, ratio, baker-percentage

Is there a baker’s ratio for crackers? I can find one for just about every dough recipe under the sun, except one for crackers! I suppose I could just research a bunch of recipes and come up with my own, but if there’s one out there that any of you know about, it would sure save me some time and headache!

Comment: exactly that, research some. Crackers are usually a mechanically leavened lean dough. Water and flour and sale and not a lot else...Agreed, though, that there aren't a lot of recipies easily floating, because so few people would think to *make* their own crackers.

Comment: Crackers do seem to be the unloved offspring of the bread world. Of professional books on breads, only "Modernist Bread" considers them at all -- as far as I can tell. There are some good recipes in "Salty Snacks" by Nims (published by Ten Speed Press). The problem there is that the author uses only volume measurements which are useless for BP. The King Arthur web site has a number of recipes for 'crackers' and it is possible to get the ingredient amounts (mostly) by weight, which would allow you to derive your own BPs.

Comment: I can add a bit more to my previous comments. "Bread" by Jeffrey Hamelman (Wiley, second edition) has recipes (good ones, I am sure) complete with BP. "Rosemary Crackers with olive oil" (page 356) and "Lavash" (page 357).